# Is 'Digit Classification Using HOG Features' matlab example only available in the 2014 version?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I use the R2013a version of matlab. I tried to follow the path,

```
syntheticDir   = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'), 'visiondemos','digits','synthetic');
handwrittenDir = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'), 'visiondemos','digits','handwritten');
```

but there were no files named digits.

Also upon running,

```
trainingSet = imageSet(syntheticDir,   'recursive');
testSet     = imageSet(handwrittenDir, 'recursive');
```

I got the following error : **Undefined function 'imageSet' for input arguments of type 'char' .**

I'm trying to attempt this example, http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html

Comment: It looks like it is.  I can't find it on my MATLAB distribution and I am running R2013a

Comment: They should atleast mention that in the website. Spent hours trying to fix it. :-/

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that right?  Usually the errors I see here where there is a function that isn't defined... is probably related to the function not being part of their MATLAB distribution.  It's a ridiculous ploy to try and entice you to upgrade so that you get all of the latest functions to do some cool stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I would consult the [**release notes**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/relnotes/index.html) of the respective toolboxes to find out when a new function was introduced.

For the [digit classification example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html) mentioned, it uses `imageSet` [a new feature in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html#buf_zw7-1), as well as the `extractHOGFeatures` function [introduced in R2013b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html#btz19jb-1). It also uses `fitcecoc` from the Statistics toolbox. This [a new function in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes.html#budsyit-2).

It would be nice if the documentation provided this information in easier way...

Comment: Are the archived documentations downloadable?

Comment: I'm afraid not, only available online (if you have multiple MATLAB versions installed side-by-side locally, then you'd have the docs of those versions offline)

Answer (score 1):

This example was added in R2013b.  Generally, if you have an older version of MATLAB, you should use the documentation that came with it. The [documentation on the web](http://www.mathworks.com/help/) is for the current release, and so it will naturally contain new examples and functions not present in the older versions. However, if you click "Other Releases", you can see the archive of the documentation for the previous releases.  This way you can easily check when a particular function or example was added.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the links to other releases don't take you to the corresponding page in the other release, but to the main table of contents / search screen.  So it is possible to check when a function was added, but not "easy"

Comment: If it is a new example, then there will not be a corresponding page in the older release. But you can click on "Examples", which will take you to the list of all the examples. Then you can search for the one you need to see if it is there.

Comment: "you can search"... Yes, and that is a darn unfriendly experience.  For an example of good multi-version links between documentation, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and click Other Versions.

Comment: Thank you Dima. That's helpful but it would have been easy on the people using it if the particular function example(like the link I posted) mentioned that this is available only in editions after R2013b. I hope the support staff incorporate it into the sites.